# How do you get from the low-pass filter formula to the code?

Tags: formula-derivation

I am just wondering how the author deduced [this](http://www.lothar-miller.de/s9y/categories/21-Filter) code from this formula. This is the step response of a low-pass filter.

$$v_{out}(t)=V_i\cdot(1-e^{-ω_0\cdot t}), \text{ where } ω_0 = \frac{1}{R\cdot C}.$$

He writes that \$128\$ serves as a time constant and `avgsum` as a "sum memory" (→capacitor).

```
unsigned long mittelwert(unsigned long newval) 
{
   static unsigned long avgsum = 0;
   // Filterlängen in 2er-Potenzen --> Compiler optimiert 
   avgsum -= avgsum/128;
   avgsum += newval;
   return avgsum/128;
}
```

@Tim Williams:
I have created a WinForms application with the VB.NET language. Something is still not right. The values start at over 1.3 instead of 0. The first value is always 3.

```
Public Class FormMain
    Private Shared Time As Single = 0F
    Private Shared ReadOnly RC As Single = 1.0F / 1.0F
    Private Shared v_o_old As Single = 0F
    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonStop.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Time += 0.4F
        If Time < 1.0F Then
            Debug.WriteLine(Synthesize_first_order_lowpass(0F))
        Else
            Dim Test As Single = Synthesize_first_order_lowpass(3.0F)
            Debug.WriteLine(Test)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function Synthesize_first_order_lowpass(v_in As Single) As Single
        Dim v_o As Single = -(RC * (v_o_old - v_o)) / Time + v_in
        v_o_old = v_o
        Return v_o
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I am absolutely sure the author did not deduce the code from this formula. He just knows that low-pass filtering can be done by averaging.

Comment: The number may be arbitrary. Anyway, the number can be calculated from the time constant and sampling rate.

Comment: It's unrelated.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the information :)

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, it is remotely related. We can deduce the Laplace transform of the transfer function, then apply it as a convolution on the input signal. Then approximate this convolution as a digital matrix operation, and will see that this matrix is actually a sliding average operator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What I meant is equation doesn't describe the filter in the code.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah, most likely. Not sure why the OP thinks otherwise.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The link itself doesn't say but I assume the claim was made elsewhere. Or the OP has only learned about RC filters so that's their one hammer so every filter looks like a nail.

Comment: Eugene, what you said about Laplace transform and matrix was still in the back of my mind.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way for this particular formula than just knowing it. It's easy to see how the code corresponds to maths, but it's different maths, but it somehow gets the same impulse response shape.

Comment: Notice your first equation is allowing you to calculate the voltage at any time t, but the code is calculating the next voltage based on the previous voltage and the input. There would be a bunch of maths to do to relate one to the other.

Comment: Has the question now transitioned how to code the equation? You could time step through it in the time domain as if it were a real circuit. That's kind of brute-forcey but should work.

Answer (score 5):

A basic way to synthesize digital filters is to consider the differential equation of the (analog, continuous time) system, then change dees to deltas.

This 1st order system has the response:
$$ \frac{d v_o}{dt} = \frac{v_{in} - v_o}{R C} $$
Changing dees to deltas, we simply get:
$$ \frac{\Delta v_o[n]}{\Delta t} = \frac{v_{in}[n] - v_o[n]}{R C} $$
Of course \$\Delta t\$ is our sample time \$T_s\$, and we can rearrange to get \$v_o\$ in terms of its previous value \$v_0[n-1]\$.  The C code follows naturally.

This is a very hand-waved approach, but it is in fact justified for 1st order systems; a bit more care is required for higher order systems (the locus of stability is different), for which we analyze using the Z transform (effectively the discrete-time equivalent of the Fourier transform).

Finally, the exact value of 1/128 is probably an efficient approximation for some usefully-slowly-varying "average", which will be implemented by most compilers as a bit shift operation.  Thus, no multiplication is required.

Comment: I have edited my question. Based on the formula (rearranged to v_o) I have written a program

Comment: @Daniel I'm not familiar with VB.NET.  What does it mean to reference a variable in its own declaration (v_o)?

Comment: @TimWilliams I think he may have wanted to use "Static" instead of "Dim" there. It doesn't make sense (it will compile and run, but doesn't make sense), as written. But I haven't bothered to look over the entire code.

Answer (score 5):

Tim Williams pretty much nailed this for you. Your *only* problem is that you didn't code it up in VB.NET, properly.

I will use the same VB.NET timer you did. It is fine. But I'm doing the rest pretty much differently. For example, I won't be using the Debug.Print() method. Instead, I'll set up a multi-line textbox in the form and put the information there.

You are setting up things so that the **RC** product is 1. The way you handle setting that up is to divide 1 by 1. This is confusing to me because \$\omega=\frac1{RC}\$ and **R** is ***multiplied*** by **C**. Not divided. I can't complain. The result may be the same as you want. But I just want to be absolutely clear, here. I will set up two Const values: one for **R** and one for **C**.

In your code, you delay an entire second of simulation time before changing the input value from 0 to 3. That's fine. But if you change the value of \$\Delta t\$, which I think you very well may want to adjust so that you can see how things converge, you might be waiting a very long time as your timer slowly progresses to that point. I changed this.

Let's examine our expectations in the output. The finer-grained setting used for \$\Delta t\$, the closer the results will be to the value predicted by the analog computation. Since you already throw away one second of simulation time, for comparison purposes we need to subtract that second in the analog equation to make predictions. For example, at \$t=2\$ in your simulation, we should expect to see \$3\cdot\left(1-e^{-1}\right)=1.89636168\$ at the output. This assumes \$R=1\$, \$C=1\$ and we are at simulation time, \$t=2\$. Note, we first subtract 1 from \$t\$ before using it. So that's the expectation in your code, I think. I'm going to change this, as I don't like the idea of subtracting 1.

I've added two buttons, like you did. And they do the same thing, turning the timer on and off, just as you do. No differences there.

I set things up like this:

```
Private Const DeltaT As Double = 0.4
Private Const R As Double = 1.0
Private Const C As Double = 1.0

Private SimulationTime As Double = 0.0
```

I don't think I need to explain that. It's self-evident.

I added this line:

```
Private MyFilter As Func(Of Double, Double, String) = FilterFactory(0.0, 0.0, 1.0 / R / C)
```

This uses the following declaration and definition:

```
Private Function FilterFactory(pv As Double, tv As Double, omega As Double) As Func(Of Double, Double, String)
    Dim LocalProcessValue As Double = pv
    Dim LocalTimeValue As Double = tv
    Dim LocalOmega As Double = omega
    Return Function(newtime As Double, newsetpoint As Double) As String
               Dim DeltaTime As Double = newtime - LocalTimeValue
               LocalProcessValue += LocalOmega * (newsetpoint - LocalProcessValue) * DeltaTime
               LocalTimeValue += DeltaTime
               Return $"{LocalTimeValue:F3}    {LocalProcessValue:F5}"
           End Function
End Function
```

The above arrangement allows you to construct many of these. Only one here, though.

For displaying the results (which will work in multi-threaded situations), I used:

```
Private UpdateStatus As IProgress(Of String) = New Progress(Of String)(
    Sub(ReportMessage As String)
        Dim UpdatedText As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(UpdatedText) Then
            UpdatedText = ReportMessage
        Else
            UpdatedText += vbCrLf & ReportMessage
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = UpdatedText
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length
        TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub)
```

The above updates the text box with the new result. And it does so in a thread-safe way. So you can create tasks, etc. And it will just work right. The Frameworks VB.NET form-based timer object is usually safe for updating a form, as I believe it is processed as a message into the STA message queue. But the Windows system timers directly invoke code running as an MTA thread. So it is just better to get into the right practice. The Progress class is the way to achieve this, as it always uses messages into the STA to achieve its results, even if these are generated in some MTA thread pool.

My timer tick looks like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    UpdateStatus.Report(MyFilter(SimulationTime, 3.0))
    SimulationTime += DeltaT
End Sub
```

Quite simple.

Let's pick a target simulation time of 1.2 seconds. We should expect to see \$3\cdot\left(1-e^{-1.2}\right)=2.09641736\$. But at an increment size of 0.4 seconds? Not so much.

Let's see:

[image]

Yup. \$2.352\$ is a bit far away. We should expect that it would be above, as we are starting with an estimated steep slope and projecting it too far, so the actual curve will always be curving away underneath those successive straight line estimates.

But it gets better with 0.1 second steps:

[image]

The shorter projections, while still always above the curve, do now appear to track it a lot better. Now we see \$2.15271\$. Closer.

Let go for broke and try 0.001 seconds per step:

[image]

We get \$2.09696\$ vs \$2.09641736\$. It's still above. But only slightly so, because we've tracked pretty closely to the actual curve. So now the result is getting pretty close to expectations.

Ich hoffe, das helfen Ihnen.

Comment: Hi jonk, thanks for your help. I had to get familiar with the arrangement first. It works great.

Comment: @Daniel Glad to hear it. I like the ability of VB.NET (and C#) to perform captures. The approach I took with the factory takes nice advantage of the use of anonymous functions and captures. In any case, I hope things are working good for you.